# Weird top margin appearing. Tracked it in Chrome to -webkit-margin-before but can't find it in Firefox

Tags: css

There is a 16px top margin being applied to an ul. But I can't figure out where it is coming from. In Firebug it shows the margin when I hover on ul and shows in the **Layout** panel, but it doesn't show anywhere in the **Computed** or **Style** panels.

In Chrome Dev tools under **Style** it does show "-webkit-margin-before: 1em;", so I guess it's some default styling for ul which I can negate by manually setting "-webkit-margin-before: 0;" in my stylesheet, but it's still the same in Firefox.

How can I figure out where this is coming from if it doesn't show anywhere Firebug?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Okay just uploaded it http://prh-demo2.solution-devices.com. It's the menu in the footer. Now it doesn't show without looking at the code because I added a heading 'Quick Links' so the bottom margin from that is making the top margin of the ul irrelevant. But if you go into the code you can still see the ul has a top margin 16px.

Answer (score 0):

Element do come up with some default margin and padding..
Have you tried giving

```
*{

Padding:0px;

Margin:0px;

}
```

And reason why the margin is not in showed firefox, chrome uses webkit layout engine for rendering, and Firefox uses gecko, and so on...
which means -webkit- property wont work on firefox browser, because it uses gecko layout, and it if that properry is not rendered then they use thier own property with -moz-
Hence it only comes in chrome, the same thing must also come in safari as safari also use webkit..

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html.    you can see in the link that ul comes with default margin before, so its better to remove all the margin & padding from every element.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why using -webkit- only effects Chrome but it's still coming from somewhere weird. If I set the margin-top to the ul to 0 it doesn't effect it, it's still the same. I've uploaded the site if you want to have a look, see my comment above in response to Michael's comment. Thanks.

Comment: margin-top wont effect, becuase the css property being used is "-webkit-margin-before", u need to set that as 0.....
Have you tried what i suggested?

giving padding and margin 0 in *?

Comment: I hope things helped, and your question was answered

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I did before. It works, but then only for Chrome. The problem is that I can't find which css property it's coming from in Firefox because it doesn't show anywhere in the 'Computed' breakdown. Anyway, I thought it's pretty strange, I've not encountered it before.